# Proper style in Swift: Guard Statement

Tags: swift

I am getting my feet wet with Swift and I am wondering what proper style for guards is. Am I using the `guard` statement correctly? It feels a little clunky, but I prefer it to an `if let` statement. Or could this be simplified?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView: UITableView?
    ...
    required init() {    
        super.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        setupUI()
    }

    // MARK: - User Interface
    func setupUI() {
        ... 
        // tableView
        tableView = UITableView()
        guard let tableView = tableView else {
            Log.msg("tableView could not be initialized")
            return
        }
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        tableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "tableView"
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        ...
    }
}
```

`Log` is a custom logging class that has optimized console output.

Comment: In this particular case it does not make any sense at all since the tableView is always initialized before you reach the `guard`.

Comment: This question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that codereview existed. Can I move the question myself?

Comment: This question has a slight risk of being closed on Code Review because of the `...` markers in your code. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) before considering moving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think this question should be moved to the codereview site, I'll mention this:

You are using the `guard` statement correctly from a syntactic point of view.  It's a way to check something and return early if the condition isn't met.  Your overall implementation needs a bit of refactoring though so you don't need the `guard` at all.

When creating a view controller, do this instead:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = {
            let tableView = UITableView()

            tableView.property = ...

            return tableView
        }()

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        // setup constraints on tableView...
    }
}
```

By using an implicitly unwrapped optional for your `tableView` property you forego the need for a `guard` and testing the `tableView` for `nil` wherever you need to use it, but you also get the benefit of deferred initialization (in `viewDidLoad()`).

Comment: Depends on what you're force unwrapping.  Certainly you wouldn't want to treat something you don't own that way, but if you own it and you understand the lifecycle force-unwrapped optionals are extremely useful.  You can even set them to `nil` and test for that when you need to.  It's all about how you manage it.

Comment: Thanks for this - it really has made the rest of my code much simpler. Do you know of something like a style guide for swift?

Comment: You're welcome, and you should ask a new question instead of extending this comment thread if you'd like additional information.  There are a few good style guides for Swift out there.  One you can start with is here: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide